# Inserting variable in mysql with visual studio CLR / C

Tags: mysql, c, visual-studio-2010, insert, clr

I used mysql connector and extract data from Database in visual studio 2010. Also inserted data successfully as value. But was fail to insert data with variable. Need a help, please.

this one worked.

```
mysql_query(connect,"INSERT INTO input VALUES(111,'Bangladesh','Khulna','Male','Muhammad Ashikuzzaman KUET','b+')");
```

But this are not working.

```
  str="Muhammad Ashikuzzaman KUET";
  mysql_query(connect,"INSERT INTO input VALUES(111,'Bangladesh','Khulna','Male','@str','b+')");
  or
  mysql_query(connect,"INSERT INTO input VALUES(111,'Bangladesh','Khulna','Male',@str,'b+')");
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the string before calling `mysql_query()`:

```
char statement[512], *str = "Muhammad Ashikuzzaman KUET";
snprintf(statement, sizeof statement, "INSERT INTO input VALUES(111,'Bangladesh','Khulna','Male','%s','b+')", str);
mysql_query(connect, statement);
```

Also, be careful when creating those query strings. Don't use functions like `sprintf()` if you cannot be sure how long the resulting string is. Don't write over the boundaries of the memory segment.

**Edit**

For precaution, You can use `mysql_real_escape_string()` additionally if the string usually comes from arbitrary sources:

```
int insertData(MYSQL *connect, char *str, int str_len) {
    if (str_len < 0) {
        str_len = strlen(str);
    }

    char esc[2 * str_len + 1];
    unsigned long esclen = mysql_real_escape_string(connect, esc, str, str_len);

    char statement[512];
    snprintf(statement, sizeof statement, "INSERT INTO input VALUES(111,'Bangladesh','Khulna','Male','%s','b+')", esc);
    return mysql_query(connect, statement);
}
```

Also here I've assumed your input string is small enough to fit into 512 characters string. Practically, it won't work. So declare `statement` length variable according to input string length plus some extra length to fit with the query string together.

Comment: If `str` can contain embedded `'` characters you need to escape it, or this could happen: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Yes I did that. char *str; at the starting of the problem before. I did not added here the whole question.

Comment: What 512 in statement[512] . The string length?

Comment: yes, its maximum the query string length. you can change it. `int snprintf ( char * s, size_t n, const char * format, ... );`